# What to call an island off the coast of an island?

Tags: geography

So, on my map, I have an island, and, off the coast of that island, another, smaller island. Is there a specific geographical term for this? Is it a sub-island? A holm? I'm looking for something along the lines of the relationship between Tanzania and Australia, just in a smaller scale. I need to know this to be able to properly name my island in my game.

Comment: This sounds like a question about geography not worldbuilding.

Comment: Consider asking this on https://english.stackexchange.com/ or **maybe** https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/ — I doubt that your question is on topic here, you're not building world, just describe it. Even if it is, English guys may be better at answering this question.

Comment: Guys, why downvotes? This seems like a valid question, just on wrong stack.

Comment: Tbh had no idea where to ask

Comment: I think it is just an island. All the islands around the UK are referred to as islands or isles.

Comment: I keep thinking "neighboring island" for this arrangement.  Holm would be technically correct too, I think, but I don't think that's a very common term.

Comment: "Holm" is a specific scandinavian term for the smaller islands on their coasts. Nothing says there has to be a larger island nearby.

Comment: I answered this just to clarify the answers, but I consider this a gray area question.  Worldbuilding basically assumes, "the rules of a world not our own."  For example, if my world has lower gravity, how will that affect construction?  However, you need the vocabulary to have the conversation.  If pressed for a choice right now, I'd call the question off-topic... but I wonder, just a bit, if it's too fine a line.

Comment: But, aren't both islands off the coast of each other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Island:** A small parcel of land wholly surrounded by water.

**Islet:** A smaller parcel of land wholly surrounded by water.

**Cay:** An even smaller parcel of land wholly surrounded by water, usually quite low (if it has a hill, it's an islet).

---

Special Mentions:

**Holm:** A small island or inshore island (chiefly British).

**Bar:** Something that obstructs or prevents passage, progress, or action: such as ... (c) :a submerged or partly submerged bank (as of sand) along a shore or in a river often obstructing navigation.

Comment: You should add enclave if it's a island off the coast that is politically connected to another entity. Exclave if it's completely surrounded by another political territory, along the lines of the Vatican. Also bar if it's a very small island.

Comment: A cay is a low elevation sandy island on top of a coral reef. An islet is simply a very small island. But generally speaking, an island off an island is simply an island. There's no special designation.

Comment: @gwally, I added "bar," that was a good catch.  I passed on enclave because I'm fairly sure the OP wasn't looking for a political reference.  Interesting, though!

Answer (score 16):

An island off the coast of an island is called an island

Comment: or an islet if it is very small

Comment: It's the truth. A lake inside an island in a lake is still a lake. And island in a lake in an island is still an island.

Comment: It is true but it's not very helpful! Like if you asked me where I am and I answered, "On my chair" ;)

Comment: @colmde If I asked you where you were either there would be context to that question or I would supply it in my question. Without said context I might as well answer a blunt question with a blunt answer. An island is a landmass surrounded by water on all sides, any classification system beyond this is fairly subjective to the answerers locality/culture and perspective. Even JBH's answer implies this fact with the mentioning of "Holm" and the absence of size requirements for islet and cay.